# Having BeautifulSoup extract "Customers Who Bought This Item Also Bought" part of Amazon Product page?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

For any given title or author, I'm trying to write a script that (for now) loads the Amazon product page and will output the items in the 'Customers Who Bought This Item Also Bought' area of the page.  I've tried to point BeautifulSoup towards it, but I'm not quite sure what name to refer to it as.  The h2 header for that section is 'a-carousel-heading', which I tried but didn't seem to work.  I also tried the div containing it ('div a-column a-span8'), but that didn't seem to work either.  Can any of you give me some pointers on how exactly to refer to the area I'm looking for?

```
book = raw_input('Enter a book title, or an author\'s name! \n')
products = amazon.search_n(1, Keywords=book, SearchIndex='All')
isbn = products[0].isbn

html = urlopen('http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/', isbn)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
for row in soup.select("div.a-column.a-span8"):
    print(row)
```

**expected output:**

```
The Basic Works of Aristotle, Aristotle: Selections, etc..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the heading, not the carousel itself. The data is stored inside:

```
<ol class="a-carousel" role="list" aria-busy="false"> 
..
```

Comment: Thanks! However, when I try and point BeautifulSoup at that [ via print(soup.find("ol", {"class": "a-carousel"})) ], it returns with "None".  Am I just using the wrong term to refer to it?

Comment: Sorry, the "ol" contains a lot of "li" items. It is the "li" items you want. Sorry, you really need to understand HTML before you attempt web scraping.